# Why am I seeing this error message when trying to seed csv data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

getting this error message in my terminal when trying to seed csv data:

rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Year(#70340979867760) expected, got 1967 which is an instance of Integer(#70340969823320)

here is my rake file code:

```
require 'csv'
namespace :albums do
  desc "pull albums data into database"
  task seed_albums: :environment do

    #drop the old table data before importing the new stuff
    Albums.destroy_all

    CSV.foreach("lib/assets/Albums.csv", :headers =>true) do |row |
      puts row.inspect #just so that we know the file's being read

      #create new model instances with the data
      Albums.create!(
      name: row[0],
      year: row[1].to_i)
    end
  end
end
```

here is my scheme code:

```
create_table "albums", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "year"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

and here is my controller code:

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_albums, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /albums
  # GET /albums.json
  def index
    @albums = Albums.all
  end


  # GET /albums/1
  # GET /albums/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /albums/new
  def new
    @albums = Albums.new (params[:album])
  end

  # GET /albums/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /albums
  # POST /albums.json
  def create
    @albums = Albums.new

    respond_to do |format|
      if @albums.save
        format.html { redirect_to @albums, notice: 'albums was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @albums }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @albums.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /albums/1
  # PATCH/PUT /albums/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @albums.update(albums_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @albums, notice: 'albums was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @albums }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @albums.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /albums/1
  # DELETE /albums/1.json
  def destroy
    @albums.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to albums_url, notice: 'albums was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_albums
      @albums = albums.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def albums_params
      params.require(:albums).permit(:name, :term)
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share a few lines of the Albums.csv file?

Comment: The csv file is an excel spreadsheet:

title year
Sgt. Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band 1967
Pet Sounds 1966
Revolver 1966
Highway 61 Revisited 1965
Rubber Soul 1965
What's Going On 1971
Exile on Main St. 1972
London Calling 1979

not sure the correct format on here for excel cells

Comment: it's basically album name, then year of release

Comment: Got it - you can format it with greater ease in the question prompt itself which would be helpful! Format is often the culprit in these cases haha